# Debugging Javascript. Is it possible to stop at the next file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I am working with angular.js, and when I have some very, very wierd bugs with angular, I get stuck stepping through debugger hell.

Is there a way to have the Javascript console break on the first line of the next file accessed?

For instance, say I stepped through into angular.js.

Instead of stepping through angular and trying to get to the first line referenced of a next file, say "myFile.js," I would just like to tell the Javascript console to stop once it reaches a line of code from a different file than it is on right now, say, stop once it hits "myFile.js", or stop when it hits a line on anything other than the file "angular.js."

I have not mentioned any specific browser, for the fact that I assume that you may be able to do this with one browser and not the other.

I also understand that I should know my code well enough to know what the next line in the next file referenced should be, but the project I am working with is quite dynamic and it takes a lot of brain-power to figure out which line of which file I will actually hit next (ugh...)

Comment: tough break, not sure that is actually available anywhere in any debugger.

Comment: a different approach, maybe not feasible for you, is to concatenate all the .js files into one and debug that?

Comment: @EliteOctagon That sounds like the exact opposite of what I want to do. lol. Wow, I'm sorry, that would be such a mess. Great security though.

Comment: I believe this is possible only in IE, but if you issue `debugger;` statement - IE breaks on that line

Comment: You can try to use breakpoints. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: You can repeatedly use the "step out" button which will step out of the current function each time you press it.  If you're buried in angular, then you can press that button several times until you find yourself back in your own source file.  This assumes that the current code path started in your source file (e.g. not an event handler that originated in angular) so you can get back to where the code path originated and that will be in your code.

Comment: The step out function will work in most cases, but yes, some of the issues I am facing deal with angular fired events. Thanks for the link Tivie, I'll look through it and see if there is something like what I am talking about. Its good to have documentation on Chromes debugger. The most interesting, @YuriyGalanter can you explain more about this IE feature? What is this about?